# I want to use numpy to make a 5 x 7 grid with spaces rather than 0s

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a grid with spaces that works the the same as a grid with 0

The fact that the are 0 in the grid is irrelevant to my code. I could make a grid of 1s 2s or anything else and the main body of code would still work as long as I change a few thing that are expecting 0s. This is my present code:

```
import numpy as np
def make_grid():
    board = np.zeros((5,7))
    return board
grid = make_grid()
print(grid)
```

this is what i am getting:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

this is what i want to get:

```
[[ .  .  .  .  .  .  .]
 [ .  .  .  .  .  .  .]
 [ .  .  .  .  .  .  .]
 [ .  .  .  .  .  .  .]
 [ .  .  .  .  .  .  .]]
```

also i have this function:

```
def location(grid, col):
    return grid[4][col] == 0
```

what do i change the **0** to once I implement your code as before it was for checking if the column was full but if the grid is space i can't just do a " " or a tap of the space bar can I, to replace the **0**.

@Hanna code does this:

```
[[' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']]
```

can i make this:

```
[[' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']]
```

Comment: `np.full((5, 7), " ")`

Comment: Print `np.array(['',' ','.','-'])`.  Does that give any ideas of what is possible?  You can makes an array with strings, including the single character `' '`.  But you can't display it without the quotes - at least not without some Python list and string manipulation.

Comment: What are those dots in the desired display supposed to represent?  Why no quotes?

Comment: This sounds like you're coupling your display logic to your internal data structure representation too much. You don't need an array that prints exactly like the board representation you want. You need an array that represents your board in a way that's useful for your program to work on it internally. Your display logic can interpret the array's contents to print something appropriate for display.

Comment: i know but im not able to do that i havent being codeing long @user2357112

Comment: FYI for displaying a dynamic content of your grid on a terminal you might consider `curses` (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the particular output with dots and spaces without quotes on the screen, try to define your own print function :)

```
import numpy as np
def make_grid():
    board = np.full((5, 7), ' ')
    return board
grid = make_grid()

def my_print(grid):
    rows, cols = grid.shape
    for i in range(rows):
        print('[', end='')
        for j in range(cols):
            print(grid[i, j], end='.')
        print(']')

my_print(grid)

"""
[ . . . . . . .]
[ . . . . . . .]
[ . . . . . . .]
[ . . . . . . .]
[ . . . . . . .]
"""
```

```
def location(grid, col):
    return grid[4][col] == ' '

location(grid, 0)  # ---> True
```

Comment: ```def location(grid, col):```
```return grid[4][col] == 0```
It is messing up this function what should I put in instead of 0 I put in ‘ ’ but it didn’t work I am getting back:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @happypanda see edited answer, it works. Not sure though why you put 4 as the row index, just copied your code and replaced 0 with space (`' '`)

Answer (score -2):

To create a grid of spaces instead of zeros, you can simply replace the call to np.zeros with a call to np.empty and pass in the desired shape of the grid as arguments. The np.empty function creates an array with uninitialized values, so the elements of the array will be spaces by default. Here is how you can modify your make_grid function to create a grid of spaces:

```
import numpy as np

def make_grid():
    board = np.empty((5,7))
    return board

grid = make_grid()
print(grid)
```

This will print the following grid:

```
[[  .   .   .   .   .   .   .]
 [  .   .   .   .   .   .   .]
 [  .   .   .   .   .   .   .]
 [  .   .   .   .   .   .   .]
 [  .   .   .   .   .   .   .]]
```

To modify the location function to work with a grid of spaces, you can simply change the comparison operator to check if the element is equal to a space character instead of zero. Here is how you can modify the location function:

```
def location(grid, col):
    return grid[4][col] == ' '
```

This will return True if the element at the specified location is a space, and False if it is not.

Keep in mind that using a grid of spaces will not work with certain operations that expect numerical values, such as arithmetic or statistical functions. In those cases, you may need to convert the grid to a numerical format before performing the operation.

Comment: Not true: "The np.empty function creates an array with uninitialized values, **so the elements of the array will be spaces by default**." Correct answer: `np.empty()` creates an array without rewriting the actual contents of the memory chunk allocated for the array, so the contents can be whatever, but definitely not anything you can count on. So use `np.full((5, 7), ' ')` instead.

Comment: By default np.empty is defined in the Docs as creating an array of type float64.  The default type can be changed.  `grid[4][col] == ' '` will be False. the @Hanna suggestion `np.full((5, 7), " ")`is the best and correct approach in my view.

Comment: this is outputting lots of very large and very small numbers in a grid for me

Comment: @happypanda those are the random rubbish contents present in your memory at the time when the memory is allocated to the array via `np.empty()`. If you use `np.ones()` the memory is rewritten to ones, if you use `np.full()` the memory is rewritten to the desired values.